# How can I effectivelly find and apply for Jr. Dev Jobs?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, applications

I'm junior level in front end, self-taught (~2k hours over ~1.8yrs). I wanted to try a job interview and see how I do, but I don't see any jobs.

I look on the big job sites(google jobs/indeed/glassdoor ect..) but they are all CV farming recruitment/consulting beginning with "my client..." or "outstanding opportunity" but no company name.

To try and be more clear, I feel like the job adverts that start with "my client.." are there to steal my identity info, and/or may be lying about the job, it puts me off applying.

Are the big job sites a way to get jobs or just an illusion. *How would you recommend I find jobs to apply for/get interviews?*

Comment: Hello Clearly and welcome to this site. If there weren't any jobs with that criteria, why would the recruiters you come across bother to temp you to send your CV?

Comment: OP your email isn't worth much, and the job boards you've signed up for are already selling it anyway. Applying for a job isn't going to cause you much more in the way of problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would you recommend I find jobs to apply for/get interviews?

Some options that come to mind are:

- **Create and use a LinkedIn profile**, so you can expose yourself to the professional workforce. There you may receive offers or well find places you may like to apply.
- **Attend to job fairs**, where you can see what companies are out there and seeking to employ developers. Be sure to bring your CV or contact card with you.
- **Participate in hackathons, dev conventions, etc.,** as recruiters and companies always attend those to head-hunt, and also is helpful to expand your contacts.
- Try looking for a job **through a Contracting Agency**, where they will "do the searching" for you and try match you with potential recruiters and companies interested in your skills.
- **Consider using [StackOverflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)**. I haven't used it thoroughly, but I see it could also be an option for you to find dev jobs.
- **Ask your contacts and acquaintances** if they know about any dev job they can redirect you to.

As an additional comment:

> I feel like the job adverts that start with "my client.." are there to steal my identity info, and/or may be lying about the job, it puts me off applying.

If you never apply you can be sure you will never get an offer. True, some offers may be fake or just wanting to lure you, but you will never know if you don't apply.

Select some options, screen and research about them, and if they seem legit or not shady consider applying. One seldom lands an offer or job on the first try; usually it takes several attempts to find one, so don't lose your hope yet, and give yourself a chance and try to apply to the jobs you screen.

Comment: @clearly77 glad I could help. I enhanced my answer with 2 new options that came to mind :)